# node-postgres: database "database_name" does not exist error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am building REST API with PERN(postgres,express,react,node). I am trying to test my user registration route on postman and when I send the request I get this error. "database [my database name] does not exist"

I checked postgres server and i can clearly see i own the database and it is created. This is my connection.

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool


const pool = new Pool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "[myuser]",
    password: "[mypassword]",
    port: 5432,
    database: "rental"
})


module.exports = pool;
```

```
      Name      |     Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
----------------+----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 lucasleiberman | lucasleiberman | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres       | postgres       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 rental         | lucasleiberman | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 rentalapp      | lucasleiberman | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0      | postgres       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres
```

Comment: Please show the output of `\l` when you connect with `psql`, so that we can see what databases there really are. Also, the output of `SHOW port;` would be interesting.

Comment: It was on port 5433, you are a godsend, thank you